# File Not Found in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this website that reads a text file stored in one folder. Everything is working fine in the localhost. But when I tried to deploy it in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the page which uses that text file produces an error. Looked through the logs of the environment, it says:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception:  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\MainApp\Design Tools\Resources\Steel Sections\AISCDatabaseV15.txt'.
```

I am using the following code to point to the file:

```
var fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Design Tools/Resources/Steel Sections/AISCDatabaseV15.txt";
```

How do I find the file in AWS Beanstalk?